# Shorten Error Message in Terminal

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, error-handling, terminal

Rails error messages in terminal are too long and contain often useless information. Is there a gem/solution to shorten rails error messages?
Example:

```
2.2.2 :012 >   puts 1.red
```

What I currently get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `red' for 1:Fixnum
from (irb):12
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/railties-       4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:110:in `start'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/console.rb:9:in `start'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:68:in `console'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands/commands_tasks.rb:39:in `run_command!'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/railties-4.2.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:17:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `block in require'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:274:in `require'
from /Users/Ben/coding/krokoapp/bin/rails:8:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `block in load'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:240:in `load_dependency'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@global/gems/activesupport-4.2.1/lib/active_support/dependencies.rb:268:in `load'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails-devise-roles/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/commands/rails.rb:6:in `call'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails-devise-roles/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/command_wrapper.rb:38:in `call'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails-devise-roles/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:183:in `block in serve'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails-devise-roles/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `fork'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails-devise-roles/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:156:in `serve'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails-devise-roles/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:131:in `block in run'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails-devise-roles/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `loop'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails-devise-roles/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application.rb:125:in `run'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@rails-devise-roles/gems/spring-1.3.6/lib/spring/application/boot.rb:18:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from /Users/Ben/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.2.2/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
from -e:1:in `<main>'2.2.2 :013 >
```

What I want: (optionally in red)

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `red' for 1:Fixnum
===>Long error message saved in e. Get full messages with 'puts e'
```

Would this be possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could try **better_errors** gem.
It provides also a better explanation of the errors via browser.

This is the [link to the github repo](https://github.com/charliesome/better_errors)

**EDIT**

If you are looking also to a customizable console (also the exception trace) try to see [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry)

Comment: pry is really awesome! I get wonderful short errors now! Thanks.

Comment: Also, I added the pry-rails gem to my gemfile which replaces the default rails console. https://github.com/rweng/pry-rails